# WSDL The data type 'xxxx: AuthorizationFilter' does not exist

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I am trying to generate classes from WSDL using visual studio  Developer command prompt for vs2017.
I am using the command :

> wsdl.exe xxx.wsdl file.xsd file2.xsd .....

the WSDL is created in `Java` and I trying to connect to WSDL from `c#` project but I get always the same problem:

> Error: The xxxServicePortBinding binding of namespace 'urn:
>   xxx3Services-1-1-0' cannot be imported.
>    - The login process cannot be imported.
>    - The data type 'urn: xxxxServiceTypes-1-1-0: AuthorizationFilter' does not exist.

I went to xsd "xxxxServiceTypes-1-1-0" and the code of AuthorizationFilter is like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="DeclareEndpointRequest_Type">
        <xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="VUNr" type="omds:VUNr" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="BasisUrlEndpoint">
                <xsd:annotation>

                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="1000"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element ref="ArtAuthentifizierung"/>
            <xsd:element name="Credentials" type="Credentials_Type">
                <xsd:annotation>

                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="AuthorizationFilter" type="cst:AuthorizationFilter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:annotation>

                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Is there is any tipp that could help me to generat classes from thee WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I should insert the reference of the source of AuthorizationFilter in my project in my case it was the `system.web.mvc`